# Python Exception Not Printing Statement Within Except Block

Tags: python, exception

I have a simple loop going in my code that is supposed to read in a bunch of dicts. Sometimes, json throws a `ValueError` while loading (i.e. the `part_row = json.loads(part)` line), and I want to catch this so my program can just continue.

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
for part in output_rows:
    try:
        part_row = json.loads(part)
        # log.warn('%s', part_row['name'])
    except ValueError:
        log.warn('part "%s" is bad to json', part)
        continue
```

Everything works normally with the try/except EXCEPT for the logging. For some reason, the log statement in the except statement is never done (or doesn't seem to be) **unless** the other log statement is uncommented. Note that this also happens if I use print instead of log. This seems like black magic to me.

If anyone has any insights into this, it would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Somehow, today, I came back to the code, commented out that line, and the code worked fine, logging happened exactly as it was supposed to. I have no idea what happened. I've done that before. I'll chalk it up to programming black magic.

**UPDATE 2**

A friend of mine suggested it could have been due to outdated .pyc files. I don't really have a way of checking, but it's worth considering.

Comment: What's your log level? Have you called `logging.basicConfig()` or otherwise set up your logger?

Comment: It's on DEBUG. I have configured it through fileConfig elsewhere in the code. It works fine... as long as both log statements are uncommented.

Comment: What exception is being caught? Perhaps the exception is raised by the `log.warn` in the `try` block, not the call to `json.loads`. This is one reason you never catch *all* exceptions, without at the very least logging the exception to see what you caught. Try catching only the `ValueError` expected from `json.loads` and see what happens.

Comment: Whoops, I totally meant to type in "ValueError" there. The code itself works fine (as long as there is a try/except) though the logging/printing not so much (if you replace logging statements with printing, it acts exactly the same).

Comment: Specifically, I was wondering if `json.loads` could succeed without `part_row['name']` being set. Then, it would only be the log/print statement that tries to access that key that raises the error, not the json load itself.

Comment: I mean, it's possible, but that'd require some ValueError from part_row['name'] and I am almost certain part_row has an attribute 'name' (not that that would throw a ValueError). Yeah, I had ValueError in my code, I just forgot to copy it over to this post.